# Creating a task inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a typical foreach loop that calls a method where the parameter is an element of the collection we're looping over; something like this:

```
foreach (byte x in SomeCollection)
{
   SomeMethod(x);
}
```

The problem is that `SomeMethod` takes a long time to run. I want to move the call into a new task so that the loop just creates the tasks and then the thread that called the loops just continues. How do I do this in a thread-safe way?

### Edit

I had a performance issue because `SomeMethod` makes several DB calls. So I converted the loop to a `Parallel.ForEach` but that didn't make much of a difference because each thread then call the DB. What I'm looking to do is just create Tasks that will **run in the background** and let the main thread continue.

Comment: There are many easy ways, can you explain what exactly you need? Do you want them to execute in parallel, waiting for all of them to finish?

Comment: Starting multiple tasks is the easy part, but since we don't know what SomeMethod is supposed to do there's no way of telling you if this will be thread safe or not. You need to provide more specific information about the code.

Comment: @nvoigt: no, I don't want them in a Parrallel; I want them in a fire-and-forget loop so that the main running thread continues execution while the tasks run in the background. I had the loop running in parallel but that requires all the iteration to complete before the main thread resumes.

Comment: @frenchie you should have mentioned the "fire-and-forget" in the initial post. Why are you concerned about thread safety if you don't care how they run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way would be to use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(SomeCollection, x => SomeMethod(x));
```

The code would wait for all calls of `SomeMethod` to complete before proceeding, but the individual calls may run in parallel.

If you don't want to wait for the calls to finish, wrap this call in `StartNew`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(SomeCollection, x => SomeMethod(x)));
```

Comment: How about `new Thread(() => Parallel.ForEach(...)).Start()`? `frenchie` stated that `the main running thread continues execution while the tasks run in the background`.

Comment: Sorry, just realized I forgot to mention it: the code I have was already converted to a Parallel.ForEach loop because I thought that would speed things up but since there's a DB call inside the method, running in Parrallel didn't help. So I'm just looking to create Tasks and move on with the main thread.

Comment: @Jashaszun Not much impressive, Why do you need a new thread just for the sake of waiting when you don't even bother about the result?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The point of the thread is not for waiting for the result -- it's for not blocking the main thread.

Comment: @Jashaszun That's what. Why on earth you do this? Why can't you just call `Task.Run` in the loop? Atleast you could save one thread by that way!

Comment: @frenchie If a call to `Parallel.Foreach` didn't do the trick, chances are, spawning multiple tasks wouldn't be of much help, either: if the bottleneck is not in the CPU, on either side (the server or the client) you wouldn't see improvements from parallelization. Consider reducing the number of times that you call the task that calls the DB - the number of roundtrips is where the inefficiencies usually are.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: that's why I want to run the calls in a fire-and-forget manner, not in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

What thread safety do you expect? This will be thread-safe:

```
foreach (byte x in SomeCollection) { Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(x)); }
```

until your method does not modify any shared state, which isn't thread-safe itself.

Comment: How this will be thread safe? Also note that your code falls under closure issue when compiling in c# 4.0 or lesser version.

Comment: @frenchie The problem with this code fragment is that the value of `x` passed to `SomeMethod` will be the last element of the collection `SomeCollection` (or some random element in the middle if you get unlucky). You need to make a temporary variable for `x` in order to work around this issue.

Comment: ah ok; it will always be the last value.

Comment: @frenchie What dasblinkenlight said and also `SomeMethod` should be thread safe to make this piece of code thread safe

Answer (score 1):

You could something like:

```
IEnumerable<Task> doWork()
{
  foreach(var x in SomeCollection)
    yield return Task.Run(()=>SomeMethod(x);
}

Task.WhenAll(doWork());
```

This will run them all at the same time.